# How do I join a table with timestamps to table of status change

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've seen answers to how to join to the nearest timestamp, but am puzzled with how to do what should be simple logic with sql.

I have a 2 tables, table 1 with [timestamp], and table 2 with [timestamp, status_change].

How would I obtain a table with [timestamp, status]?

I could do this with a program by getting a list of start and end time for each status from table 2, then for each timestamp in table 1 loop through the list and assign a status.

What would be the sql equivalent of this?

Comment: Seems like everything can come from table 2 here, so what purpose does table 1 serve? And "nearest" needs more definition. Better yet, post a script containing DDL, sample data, and your expected results to encourage others to look at your issue.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the timestamps from `t1` and the statuses from `t2`.  A correlated subquery (or lateral join) does this:

```
select t1.*,
       (select top (1) t2.status
        from t t2
        where t2.timestamp <= t1.timestamp
        order by t2.timestamp desc
       ) as status
from t1;
```

An alternative method uses `lead()` with `left join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.status
from t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             lead(timestamp) over (order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.timestamp >= t2.timestamp and
        (t1.timestamp < t2.next_timestamp or t2.next_timestamp is null);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not aware of the correlated subquery function in sql. After reading about that functionality, the your answer makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is pretty much the same as Gordon Linoff's, but with a CTE and a coalesce instead:

```
with T2Range as (
   select status
        , Timestamp as From_Timestamp
        , lead(Timestamp) over (order by Timestamp) as To_Timestamp
     from T2
)
select T1.myValue
     , T2Range.Status as T2Status
  from T1
left join T2Range 
    on T1.Timestamp between T2Range.From_Timestamp and coalesce(T2Range.To_Timestamp,T1.Timestamp);
```